# Test MoveIt Package

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I try to make a moveIt package. I follow the tutorial and finish it without problems, but when I try to launch the new package with "roslaunch new_moveit_package demo.launch"

**[demo.launch] is neither a launch file in package [new_moveit_package] nor is [new_moveit_package] a launch file name**

Any idea??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151866/test-moveit-package/) by [rcj1986](https://answers.ros.org/users/14706/rcj1986/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2014-04-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on 2014-04-11**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/151656/problem-with-ikfast_moveit-tutorial/

**Comment by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on 2014-04-11**:
what tutorial did you do?

**Comment by [rcj1986](https://answers.ros.org/users/14706/rcj1986/) on 2014-04-11**:
This http://aeswiki.datasys.swri.edu/rositraining/Exercises/3.3

**Comment by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on 2014-04-11**:
http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Kinematics/IKFast
Try the part "Create plugin" of this Tutorial.
if you did correctly the moveit assistante tutorial, it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like your newly created package is not in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. See these Q/As for more info on that: [1](http://answers.ros.org/question/46501/ros-newbie-and-questions-about-adding-to-ros_package_path/), [2](http://answers.ros.org/question/70435/confusion-with-ros_package_path/), [3](http://answers.ros.org/question/62520/ros_package_path-environment/). You either have to put your new package into a folder that is already in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, or add your package folder to it.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rcj1986](https://answers.ros.org/users/14706/rcj1986/) on 2014-04-13**:
Thanks, when I save the package in my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH it works!!